# Prioritizing one sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, sensors

I want to ask is there a possible code to prioritize a specific part of a code? So I'm doing this project where I want to utilize muscle sensor, servo, and a button on an app over Bluetooth. The problem is since all is running in void() loop, even though I am not using the muscle sensor I can't move the servo with the app, since it reads the muscle sensor first. So is there a possible code to make the muscle sensor stop for a period of time after the button is pressed on the app and the servo is moved?

Here is the code:

```
void loop() 
 {
  if(Serial.available()>0)
   {
    char data = Serial.read();

      if (data == 'a')
       {
        myservo.write(15);
       }
  }



int value = analogRead(EMG_PIN);

 if(value > THRESHOLD)
  {
   myservo.write(15);
  }

  else{
       myservo.write(140);
      }
```

So the first code is a bluetooth code where the servo is controlled through a button on an app. The second one is a muscle sensor. As stated above the problem is it will always read the muscle sensor even though the button is pressed from the app.

```
#include <Servo.h> 

 int increment = 0;

 Servo myservo;

 void setup() {

   myservo.attach(1);

 }

 void loop() 
 {

   Serial.println(increment++);

   if (increment > 9);
    {

     if(Serial.available()>0)
      {
       char data = Serial.read();

       if (data == 'a')
       {
        myservo.write(15);
       }
 }

      else if (increment = 0);

      int value = analogRead(EMG_PIN);

      if(value > THRESHOLD)
       {
        myservo.write(15);
       }

     else{
       myservo.write(140);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answerable. The answer is "Yes, there's a way." Provide your current loop code, and highlight the relevant sections where you read the muscle sensor, and where the servo code doesn't get called. It sounds to me like a simple logic problem with your code but we can't tell without **seeing** the code.

Comment: why do you need code to stop the muscle sensor? .... does it have a "stop" function? ....... why don't you simply read it only every10th iteration of loop()?

Comment: @DuncanC Ok guys I already edited my post, and putted in my code, i hope it will give you a better hindsight

Comment: @jsotola I'm new to this stuff, so I don't really know how to do it :), can you show me an example code from my code above, it would really help thx

Comment: @jsotola is it something like that, second code, im still new to thus so a bit confused

Comment: something like that .... it looks like to have mismatched braces `{}`  ..... your indentation levels are messed up so it is not clear just by looking at your code

Comment: Note that the line `else if (increment = 0);` had 3 fatal flaws:

Comment: (1) It should use `==`, not `=` (`=` is an assignment, so it assigns 0 to `increment` and then the if statement always fails.

Comment: (2) you should never put a semicolon after an `if` statement. That results in `if (condition) {do nothing}` since a semicolon marks an empty statement.

Comment: (3) You are missing a brace after the `if` statement. Code like `if (condition) statement` is legal, but confusing and error-prone. That only executes that one statement if the `if` is true, and then falls through to the statement after the if. If your indentation is wrong, you might think the if statement will only execute ALL the indented code if the `if` statement is true, but that is not correct.

Comment: Ahh ill look into that thx a lot @DuncanC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of your program as having two distinc modes of
operation:

- The "fixed servo" mode is entered when you press the button on the
  app. In this mode the servo is kept at a fixed position. The mode
  lasts for a predefined delay.
- The normal (not fixed servo) mode is the default mode. In this mode
  the servo is positioned according to the reading of the sensor.

So you need a boolean variable to remember whether the "fixed servo"
mode is active or not, and the code in `loop()` should take care of
providing the correct behavior depending on the mode, and updating that
variable when needed. For example:

```c++
void loop()
{
    static bool fixed = false;  // whether we are in "fixed servo" mode
    static uint32_t fixed_started;  // when the mode started
    uint32_t now = millis();

    // On button press, start "fixed servo" mode.
    if (Serial.available() && Serial.read() == 'a') {
        servo.write(SERVO_LEFT);
        fixed = true;
        fixed_started = now;
    }

    // Get out of "fixed" mode after some delay.
    if (fixed && now - fixed_started >= FIXED_DELAY) {
        fixed = false;
    }

    // If not in "fixed" mode, react to the sensor.
    if (!fixed) {
        if (analogRead(EMG_PIN) >= THRESHOLD) {
            servo.write(SERVO_LEFT);
        } else {
            servo.write(SERVO_RIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see it worked perfectly thx Edgar

Comment: Well done, figuring out the OPs intent from that jumble of code.